# Transmission parameters in to the function in openCL

Tags: opencl, gpu

Have following kernel function:

```
   private static String programSource =
        "__kernel void sampleKernel(__global float *Y, __global  float *param) "
        + "{ int index = get_global_id(0); "
        + "  Y[index]=param[0]-Y[index]/param[1]-param[2]; "
        + "} ";
```

First argument  "Y" works perfect, but second parameter "param" works non correct, I receive null values . Second parametr must be a array and consists from 3 cells.

Fragment of code with the transmission parameters:

```
        float[] arr_params = new float[3];
        arr_params[0] = (float) h_c;
        arr_params[1] = (float) sy;
        arr_params[2] = (float) dy;

        //pointers
        Pointer Pvy = Pointer.to(vy);
        Pointer Parr_params = Pointer.to(arr_params);

        cl_mem memObjects[] = new cl_mem[2];

        memObjects[0] = clCreateBuffer(context,
                CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
                Sizeof.cl_float * vy.length, Pvy, null);
        memObjects[1] = clCreateBuffer(context,
                CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
                Sizeof.cl_float * arr_params.length, Parr_params, null);

        // Set the arguments for the kernel
        clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0,
                Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[0]));
        clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1,
                Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[1]));

        // Set the work-item dimensions
        long global_work_size[] = new long[]{vy.length};
        long local_work_size[] = new long[]{1};

        // Execute the kernel
        clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 1, null,
                global_work_size, local_work_size, 0, null, null);

        // Read the output data
        clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, memObjects[0], CL_TRUE, 0, vy.length * Sizeof.cl_float, Pvy, 0, null, null);
        // Release kernel, program, and memory objects
        clReleaseMemObject(memObjects[0]);
        clReleaseMemObject(memObjects[1]);
```

Comment: What is the `Pointer` allover in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second buffer is all zeros because, in the clCreateBuffer call, you haven't told OpenCL where to get the data. Use CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR or CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR.

Comment: To clarify - since you are passing a pointer to clCreateBuffer, you should tell OpenCL what to do with to initialize the buffer (using one of the two flags mentioned). Otherwise, you should use clEnqueueWriteBuffer to send data from host memory.